# jQuery UI Dialog error with button causing HierarchyRequestError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-templates

I have a piece of javascript that I use just fine in other pages but is throwing an HierarchyRequestError in a new page.  That has me suspect that is an issue with the HTML in my page.  Here is a vastly simplified version of the code (which still produces the error):

```
window.webframe.loginDialog = function () {
    $("body").append('<div id="dialogSpace" />');
    $("#dialogSpace").load("/login/index #loginContainer", function () {
        $("#loginContainer").dialog({
            buttons:
            [
                {
                    text: "Hi",
                    click: function()
                    { alert('Hi');}
                }
            ]
            });
    });
};

$('#lnkLogin').click(function () {
    webframe.loginDialog();
    return false;
});
```

If I run this code I get the following error from jQuery:

> HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point
>   in the hierarchy

If I remove the button definition then the error goes away.  It makes no difference if the buttons option itself is there, but if I put in a single button handler of any kind the error occurs.  I have also tried both styles of defining the buttons in the option.

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.23 and I have tried upgrading to jQuery 1.8 with no change.

As I say above I strongly suspect that this an issue of HTML structure since the exact same code file works elsewhere with a different page just fine and I will keep looking at that, but this is odd enough I wanted to see if this rings a bell with anyone else.

Update: I went through all of my other js references and found that including jquery.template (https://bitbucket.org/stanlemon/jquery-templates/) is what is causing it.  Tried updating to latest but that is 3 years old and the problem persists.  Will have to port my existing code to an up to date template lib.

Comment: Matthew, can you throw together a jsfiddle with the html as well. I would like to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be the answer you are looking for, but I also had the same problem. Upgrading to jQuery 2.02 and jQuery UI 1.10.4 did not remove the problem. In the end I removed jquery.template.js.

Comment: Yes removing jQuery.Template is what we ended up doing as well.  Thanks for the attention to such an old question.